# intercept ajax call with bootstrap 3 modal

Tags: asp.net-web-api, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I want to open a bootstrap dialog where the html is loaded from the server at Customers/Edit endpoint. But the server wants for the Edit method an id how can I attach this id to the automatic ajax call clicking on the bootstrap button?

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="/Customers/Edit/?" data-target="#modal">Click me</a>
```

Should I rather use jquery to intercept the button click? and do a manual ajax call?

**UPDATE**

This is what the user id doing:

When the page is loaded:

1) The user selects a node in the treeview.

1.5) The node has a name + id.

2) The user clicks the update/edit button.

3) A dialog is opened where the name should appear and the id should be hidden in an input field

All that worked with jquery dialogs.

Now I move to bootstrap and there seems no flexibility with the html only way of doing modals.

Comment: You don't say what server-side technology you're using, but when you render your page, you need to build the link dynamically and include the id as a paremeter: e.g "@Url.Action("Edit", new {id=@MyModel.Id })

Comment: I use Web Api NOT Razor what you used ;-) I can NOT build the link dynamically on page load because I do not yet know the id of the entity that is going to be updated in the modal dialog... I have not seen any samples on the WWW how to deal with that case use bootstrap modal with html only...

Comment: I don't think I understand fully. At what point DO you know the id of the entity?

Comment: I updated my question with a sample.

Comment: ok I understand. I think you'd have to use javascript as you suggested. You could add the id and name parameters to the modal url when the user selects a node in the treeview.

Comment: OK everytime I click a node then I update the button remote/href attribute with the selected node id. That could work. Thanks.